# Managing the health and well being of multiple pods with dependencies

Tags: error-handling, kubernetes

We have several pods (as service/deployments) in our k8s workflow that are dependent on each other, such that if one goes into a `CrashLoopBackOff` state, then all these services need to be redeployed.

Instead of having to manually do this, is there a programatic way of handling this?

Of course we are trying to figure out why the pod in question is crashing.

Answer (score 1):

If these are so tightly dependant on each other, I would consider these options
a) Rearchitect your system to be more resilient towards failure and tolerate, if a pod is temporary unavailable
b) Put all parts into one pod as separate containers, making the atomic design more explicit

If these don't fit your needs, you can use the Kubernetes API to create a program that automates the task of restarting all dependent parts. There are client libraries for multiple languages and integration is quite easy. The next step would be a custom resource definition (CRD) so you can manage your own system using an extension to the Kubernetes API.

Comment: I like the idea of adding multiple containers to a single pod.

Comment: I've been looking at the various design patterns for deploying multiple containers in a pod. My use case requires that there are three containers: Two, which need to be service/deployments (needed for the hostname in order to communicate across the workflow) and the third which is a client that fire up the process that uses the deployed services to process data. Do you think the sidecar pattern makes sense for the client? If so, how would I spin up my two containers as a `deployment` spec before spinning up the sidecar? If not, then what would you suggest?

Comment: Why do you need to restart everything if you deploy a new version/restart the application? The kubernetes service object provides a stable hostname and stable ip address, so you can restart the underlying application and the dependent applications just need to reconnect after a failure

Comment: I did not mean that the kubelet needed to be restarted. Said application has two dependent services that need to be redeployed in the event of a failure so that they can sync up with each other. The client needs to be restarted in order to reconnect to the application and continue processing at the point where failure occurred.

Comment: The question is how to automatically restart the failed container process without failing again. I assume use of a liveness probe as outlined by @vasily angapov would restart all the containers in a good state without the need to redeploy all pods.

Comment: I would just let the dependent service try to (re)establish a connection every x seconds after a failure. When the connection is back, the application can resynchronize itself.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do is making sure that pods are started in correct sequence. This can be done using initContainers like that:

```
spec:
  initContainers:
  - name: waitfor
    image: jwilder/dockerize
    args:
    - -wait
    - "http://config-srv/actuator/health"
    - -wait
    - "http://registry-srv/actuator/health"
    - -wait
    - "http://rabbitmq:15672"
    - -timeout
    - 600s
```

Here your pod will not start until all the services in a list are responding to HTTP probes.

Next thing you may want to define liveness probe that periodically executes curl to the same services

```
  spec:
    livenessProbe:
      exec:
        command:
        - /bin/sh
        - -c
        - curl http://config-srv/actuator/health &&
          curl http://registry-srv/actuator/health &&
          curl http://rabbitmq:15672
```

Now if any of those services fail - you pod will fail liveness probe, be restarted and wait for services to become back online.

That's just an example how it can be done. In your case checks can be different of course.

Comment: Thanks. One question comes to mind: If I have a daemonset or deployment with multiple replicas, then would all instances have to go down in order to fail the liveness probe?